# Simultaneously maintain a dial up connection (to a data logger on site) and the internet (Ethernet)

Tags: windows-xp, dial-up

I dial up into one of our data loggers, and ftp some files from it. I was wondering if there is a way to maintain the internet connection (connected through Ethernet / LAN)

Comment: Are there any specific problems you are having? I never had problems with dial-up and Ethernet running at the same time.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - I get disconnected from the internet

Answer (score 0):

*I don't have a second connection to test this on, but try anyway. Post a comment if any step fails, or if I'm doing it entirely wrong.*

---

Configure the network to only route *some* packets through the dial-up connection:

1. Find out the dial-up connection's default gateway. It's in the *Status* window of the connection, in `ipconfig`, and (if you know what to look for) in `route print`.

   1½. Find out the data logger's IP address using `nslookup dataloggers-hostname`
2. Disable addition of the default gateway for your dial-up connection.

   - Connection properties → Networking → TCP/IP → Properties → Advanced...
   - Disable *Use default gateway on remote network*
3. When you connect, add a route to just the data logger.

   ```
   route add 12.34.56.78 12.0.0.1
   ```

   where `12.34.56.78` would be the data logger's address and `12.0.0.1` the gateway's address (which you wrote down in step 1).
4. Test.
5. If it works, and you want it to persist reboots, then add the same route again, with `route -p ...` this time.